# Tool to show Google Drive folder associated with my Google account - Android app development

Tags: api, google-drive, web-apis, android-app

I am an Android app developer and I would like to build an app displaying the files in a Google Drive folder (a folder which anyone with a link can view) associated with my Google account. Drive files of the users will not be accessed, and there is no scope of uploading files by the users of the app. Users of the app must not be prompted to sign in. New files will be added to the shared Drive folder from time to time.

I know I can do this by opening the Drive link in WebView, and I have already tried that.

Is there a better way? Is Drive API meant for this? Can I even customize the UI when the app shows the contents of folders? I have read the Drive API documentation and found it confusing.

Comment: Please correct me if this is not the correct platform to ask this question.